# Xamarin is not being added to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

So I installed Visual studio 2017 Community 15.5.4 and I added Xamarin workload as specified in this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/windows/). I also added other workloads that I would need with that.

However, Xamarin is not being added. When I open the "About Microsoft Visual Studio" to check the installed products, Xamarin is not there, even though I double checked the installer, and the Xamarin workload is selected.
I deleted VS multiple times and re-installed it, but to no avail.

What should I do to fix this? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall whole VS, or restart PC after installation, cuz this behaviour looks odd

Comment: I did, multiple times, with no avail. Xamarin works fine on my VS 15 installation, but I need to use VS17 for a new project.

Comment: @Aissasa can you the Xamarin project templates when you are creating a new project?

Comment: Nope, thats how I noticed the first time. It even does not open Xamarin projects.